# Selenium script fails due to AJAX loader

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate an application, which has AJAX loader. It throws error (**org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (682, 395). Other element would receive the click**), when I try to click on element and the loader is active at that time. The element is not accessible.

I have created a wrapper method for click(), which makes sure that the AJAX is completed and element can be clicked.

I tried jQuery.active === 0. But, after that also, it fails due to loader.

So, I used isElementPresent for loader in the wrapper method. But, it is taking huge time apporx. 6-8 seconds for isElementPresent. I tried className, cssSelector for loader. But, no luck.

Below is my code:

```
 public void WaitForAjax() throws InterruptedException {

    while (true) {

        Boolean ajaxIsComplete = (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
                .executeScript("return (document.readyState == 'complete') && (jQuery.active === 0);");
        if (ajaxIsComplete) {
            if (isElementPresent(By.className("z-loading-indicator"))) {
                continue;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
}


   public void clickElement(WebElement element) throws InterruptedException {
    WaitForAjax();
    Thread.sleep(500);
    waitForElementVisible(element);
    waitForElementClickable(element);
    element.click();
   }
```

Please help!

Comment: You should try `ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated` instead of all those..

Comment: When you say "throws an error" it's always useful to say what the error is.

Comment: @apokryfos: Updated the question.

Comment: @SaurabhGaur: Already tried that. It also takes 6-8 seconds to click. :(

Comment: You really don't want to chain all those waits together and definitely not on every click. That's likely where all your time is being wasted. I would avoid overly generic functions like this clickElement(). The WaitForAjax() is clearly not working or you wouldn't need all the other waits. I would suggest that you find an element state that indicates that the AJAX portion is complete. Wait for that to appear and then you know AJAX is done. For example, an element appears or disappears, etc.

Comment: You also should make sure you aren't mixing implicit and explicit waits. Read more about this on the selenium site: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits

Comment: Hi @JeffC: Got the point. It was implicit wait causing the improper waiting period. Removed it. Now, it is working perfectly fine. Thanks a tn for the help! -Cheers

Answer (score 1):

@Bhargav try the following code with xpath or any other seleniumBy method.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath('xpath of the loader...')));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is likely the best way to do what you are trying to do. The long delay is likely because of all the stacked waits you have in your click element or possibly from a mix of implicit and explicit waits. See my comments above.